# vb.net check if database value is null

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

i am running a query in vb.net and i want to test if the column is null. i have tried:

```
If reader.GetString(2) IsNot Nothing Then

If IsDBNull(reader.GetString(2)) Then

If reader.GetString(2) IsNot NULL Then

If NOT reader.GetString(2) IS Nothing Then

If NOT reader.GetString(2) IS NULL Then
```

but they all return:

```
Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.
```

when i run my query in MySQL, the columns show `NULL`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the `GetString` method that internally cast your row value to a string. If the row value is null you get the exception.

The fix is using the VB.NET ternary operator

```
Dim result = IF(reader.IsDbNull(2), "", reader.GetString(2))
```

or if you don't want to assign a default value when the third field is null you could simply write

```
if Not reader.IsDbNull(2) Then
   .......
End if
```

Comment: can i use `IsNotNull` instead?

Comment: Sorry but IsNotNull? I am not familiar with this. Where do you have found it?

Comment: i didnt, thats why i was asking. or should  i do `If Not reader.IsDBNull(2) Then`

Comment: but i want to check if its NOT null and not if it IS null

Comment: _reader.IsDBNull_ returns true if the field contains _DBNull.Value_. The Not operator negate the result so _If Not reader.IsDbNull(2) Then_ enters the if only when the third field of the reader is not null.

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference:

You have a couple of ways to check if the db value is or is not null.
The examples are here with full namespace.

```vb
Dim reader As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader
Dim fieldIndex As Integer = 0

' reader(fieldIndex) is equivalent to reader.Item(fieldIndex)
Dim fieldValue As Object = reader.Item(fieldIndex)

Dim isFieldValueNull As Boolean

' Namespace: System.Data.SqlClient; Class: SqlDataReader
isFieldValueNull = reader.IsDBNull(fieldIndex)

' Namespace: Microsoft.VisualBasic; Module: Information
isFieldValueNull = Microsoft.VisualBasic.IsDBNull(fieldValue)

' Namespace: System; Class: Convert
isFieldValueNull = System.Convert.IsDBNull(fieldValue)

' Namespace: System; Class: DBNull
isFieldValueNull = System.DBNull.Value.Equals(fieldValue)
```

Note: `DBNull.Value` always has an instance of `DBNull` therefore it is never `Nothing`!

If you would like to check if the database value is not null then you can put the `Not` keyword before the method call.

```vb
Dim isFieldValueNotNull As Boolean

isFieldValueNotNull = Not reader.IsDBNull(fieldIndex)
isFieldValueNotNull = Not Microsoft.VisualBasic.IsDBNull(fieldValue)
isFieldValueNotNull = Not System.Convert.IsDBNull(fieldValue)
isFieldValueNotNull = Not System.DBNull.Value.Equals(fieldValue)
```