# List view does not give the exact value in database

Tags: vb.net

I have this program calling the out_time but it doesn't give me the exact value of date and time and i create a condition to give the value i want but it doesn't work. What is the problem of the code?

```
    Dim strdate As String
    Dim prevmonth As Integer
    prevmonth = Month(DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -1, Date.Now()))

    'Dim sqlcmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM attendance where Date(in_time) = Date(Now())", conn)
    Dim sqlcmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM attendance where Month(in_time) = Month(Now()) and Year(in_time) = Year(Now()) or Month(in_time) = " & prevmonth & " and Year(in_time) = Year(Now())", conn)
    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader

    dr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader

    If dr.HasRows Then
        While dr.Read
            Dim newitem As New ListViewItem()
            newitem.Text = dr.Item("id".ToString) 'first column
            newitem.SubItems.Add(dr.Item("employees_id").ToString)
            strdate = Format(dr.Item("in_time"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
            'dateformatter.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss")
            newitem.SubItems.Add(strdate)
            If dr.Item("out_time").ToString = "01/01/0001 12:00:00 AM" Or dr.Item("out_time").ToString = "0000-00-00 00:00:00" Or dr.Item("out_time").ToString = "0001-01-01 00:00:00" Then
                strdate = "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
                newitem.SubItems.Add(strdate)
            Else
                strdate = Format(dr.Item("out_time"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                newitem.SubItems.Add(strdate)
            End If
            newitem.SubItems.Add(dr.Item("note").ToString)
            newitem.SubItems.Add(dr.Item("employees_id").ToString & Format(dr.Item("in_time"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") & strdate)

            lvServer.Items.Add(newitem)

        End While
    End If
```

Listview on run calling it:

[image: Listview on run calling it]

This must be calling in database:

[image: This must be calling in database]

EDIT : When i put a breakpoint inside of if condition it won't stop it means it directly going in else and not reading it as `0000-00-00 00:00` or any other condition inside of my if.

Comment: Is there any chance that instead of using a date with all zeros (note that there is no month between December and January, and there is not a 0th of any month), you could use a NULL value in the database?

Comment: ... And are those datetimes stored as datetimes in the database or as strings?

Comment: @AndrewMorton it's datetime.

Comment: From the MySQL documentation [11.3 Date and Time Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-types.html): "“Zero” date or time values used through Connector/ODBC are converted automatically to NULL because ODBC cannot handle such values." So it looks like you should check for NULL: [vb.net check if database value is null](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37218504/1115360).

Comment: I don't think the check for `.HasRows` is necessary. `.Read` will return False immediately for an empty Reader.

Comment: Don't hold your connection open while you update the user interface. Build a list of `ListViewItem` and after you closed and dispose your database objects, Use the `.AddRange` method of the `ListView` and pass the list with `.ToArray`.

Answer (score 0):

I Change the first condition instead of `01/01/0001 12:00:00 AM` I Changed it into `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM` and now it's working [Sample it's working now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73d18.png) My bad guys sorry for wasting your time.

```
If dr.Item("out_time").ToString = "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM" Or dr.Item("out_time").ToString = "0000-00-00 00:00:00" Or dr.Item("out_time").ToString = "0001-01-01 00:00:00" Then
                strdate = "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
                newitem.SubItems.Add(strdate)
            Else
                strdate = Format(dr.Item("out_time"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                newitem.SubItems.Add(strdate)
            End If
```